# Зачем нужен return при повторном вызове функции из кода?

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, которая перемножает цифры одного числа до тех пор, пока не получится однозначное число.
**Пример:**

> 999 --> 2
> 9*9*9 = 729
> 7*2*9 = 126
> 1*2*6 = 12
> 1*2 = 2

Я написал функцию, но она почему-то возвращает значение `undefined`:

```
function persistence(num) {
    num = String(num);
    let newNum = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        newNum = newNum * Number(num[i]);
    };
    if (newNum > 9) {
        persistence(newNum);
    } else {
        return newNum;
    }
 }
```

Путем долгих проб я нашел решение:

```
function persistence2(num) {
    num = String(num);
    let newNum = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        newNum = newNum * Number(num[i]);
    };
    if (newNum > 9) {
        return persistence2(newNum);
    } else {
        return newNum;
    }
 }
```

Здесь добавлен еще один `return` в момент перезапуска функции при обнаружении двузначного числа, но зачем там нужен этот `return` я до сих пор понять не могу, можете мне объяснить, прочему оно работает.

Comment: В некоторых случаях (лучше всегда, для чистоты кода) функции стоит указать принудительно (прописать return), что надо непросто вполнить код, но и вернуть его результат в место вызова функции. Прочитайте больше про сам return, поднятие переменных и области видимости перменных.

Comment: Странный вопрос. Вы хотите, чтобы функция вернула вычисленное значение, но удивляетесь 'undefined', когда лишаете ее такой возможности. Представьте первый вызов peristence(). Если вычисленное значение > 9, то будет следующий рекурсивный вызов, но для текущего вызова это последняя инструкция, и если явно ничего не вернуть, то получим undefined.

Comment: Всем спасибо! Разобрался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтоб понять, что идет не так в функции `persistence` давайте мысленно её продебажим:

1. Подадим ей на вход число 25.
2. После цикла в newNum будет число 10
3. 10 больше 9, значит мы будем делать `persistence(newNum);`
4. Далее мы снова попадаем в нашу функцию, на вход пришло 10
5. Считаем произведение, получаем 0
6. 0 меньше, чем 9, тогда мы возвращаем 0
7. Вернулись к первому вызову.

И тут вы должны были понять, где проблема. Когда мы вернулись обратно, мы никуда не присвоили значение, полученное из функции.
Мало того, далее мы просто вышли из неё т.к. после вызова `persistence(newNum);` нет никакого кода.
Однако что же тогда вернет наша функция? А ничего она не вернет, что вы и получили.
Во втором же варианте, когда в `newNum` хранится число больше 9, оно в любом случае вернет его обратно и так, обратной рекурсией дойдет до места, где вы вызывали функцию.

На случай, если вы всё еще не поняли в чем проблема, попробуйте посидеть с дебагером, поэтапно разбирая что делает код (рекомендую взять число 999 т.к. там много итераций, где можно посмотреть на работу программы и число 24 т.к. там будет всего 1 итерация)